# Debugging JavaFX - compile failed: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getCause()" because "cause" is null

Tags: maven, debugging, javafx, compilation

I have created a JavaFX application WITHOUT using Maven.

Now, I want to transfer my application to a Maven project, because as it seems deploying a JavaFX application is pretty much impossible without using Maven.

Therefore, I have created a new Maven-Project in IntelliJ. I have copied the files to the new project and everything seems to be ok - there are no error messages given by IntelliJ.

However, when I run the compile-task, the following error message occurs:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project SchoolManagementSystem: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getCause()" because "cause" is null
```

This is not a very specific error message to me: It does not tell me the line which causes the error. I really need to know a line in order to do sth. So, my question is:

Has anyone encountered an error message like this one in the context of a JavaFX application before?

Is this related to the libraries that I am loading? Or what exactly is this that the compiler tries to load and fails to do so?

Answer (score 3):

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
             <configuration>
                 <release>15</release>
             </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: It would be better that explaining with words.

Comment: 3.8.0 giving me the same problem. I set it to 3.8.1 and it worked. I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

While using IntelliJ to create a Maven JavaFX project you must create the project from javafx-maven-archetypes. Here you can get steps to create a Maven JavaFX project: 
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Hi Varun, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please copy the main points from the link so that the details can be preserved in case the link is not available in the future. Moreover, you can also check [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for reference